# Foreach assist using class-variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-templates

If i use the fore-each-template for the following values using

- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>  in line 5
- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in line 8
- <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in line 11

the following code will be produced (by Eclipse 4.2)

```
01  public static String[] c = new String[]{"hi"};
02  public static void test() {
03   String[] a = new String[]{"hi"};
04   int[] b = new int[]{2};
05   for (String string : a) {
06     // 1. fine
07   }
08   for (int i : b) {
09     // 2. fine too
10   }
11   for (iterable_type iterable_element : c) {
12     // 3. not resolved?
13   }
14 }
```

Now the question:

1. Why cant the Array `c` resolve it's Array-Type and name?
2. May this be a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: Interesting. With Kepler, I'm not given the option to work with `c` at all. I just get `a` and `b`.

Comment: Might this belong on programmers.stackexchange.com perhaps?

Comment: Cool, looks like you're correct

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com is for conceptional questions right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template for while,

```
while (${condition:var(boolean)}) {
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
}
```

The `${condition:var(boolean)}` does match members and static members. 
Note that the content-assist for var says:

> ${id:var(type[,type]*)}
>   Evaluates to a field, local variable or parameter 
>    visible in the current scope that is a subtype of any 
>    of the given types. If no type is specified, any non-
>    primitive variable matches.

In the template for foreach, the template variable is different:

```
for (${iterable_type} ${iterable_element} : ${iterable}) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

The doc for the `${iterable}` variable states:

> A proposal for an iterable (array or 
>    java.lang.Iterable)

It is not specific on whether (static) members should be proposed or not.

EDIT: [this documentation page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm) states that

> ${iterable}   Evaluates to a proposal for an iterable or array visible in the current scope.

So according to the doc, this could in fact be a bug. It has actually already been reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330641).